# Xamarin.Forms : display value of a field from a sqlite database in a picker

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, data-binding, picker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcakB.png)My Xamarin.Forms application stores data in a sqlite database.
In this database, I have an Article table defined as follows:

```
public class Article
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NomCat { get; set; }
    public string UniteMesure { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageArt { get; set; }
}
```

When the user modifies an article, I display the different fields so that the user can modify them. There are 2 fields (NomCat and Unitemesure) which are entered in a picker at the time of creation.
I would like that when the page opens to modify the article, the picker displays the value contained in the table. Currently, the picker input field is empty, while all the other fields are displayed correctly with a binding.
If I define the Picker.ItemsSource in the xaml code with an array, the value of the field is displayed:

```
<Picker x:Name="pickerCat"
                    Title="choisissez une catégorie"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding NomCat}">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Fruits</x:String>
                        <x:String>Légumes</x:String>
                        <x:String>Crèmerie</x:String>
                        <x:String>Charcuterie</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
```

If the table is defined in the code behind, nothing is displayed:

```
        List<string> pkListCat = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_CategorieList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.NomCat;
            pkListCat.Add(element);
        }
        pickerListCat = pkListCat.ToArray();
        pickerCat.ItemsSource = pickerListCat;
```

I have searched for a long time but I have found nothing. Did I make a mistake or is this a problem with xamarin.forms? Thanks to whoever can help me.

Comment: Please make sure `pkListCat` have data. I used static data, I used your way, it display correctly. Here is running screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/bi0TtwN

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the problem is not to fill the list (it's OK), but to display in the picker the content of the field saved when opening the page. This works with the array defined in the xaml code, but not with the array defined in the code behind.

Comment: You do not set `mypicker.SelectedItem = "xxx";` in your backgroud code.

Comment: I have already tried: whether it is defined or not, it does not change anything. The value NomCat is not displayed in the picker when the page opens. The most disturbing thing is that if the user validates the page without refilling the pickers, the fields of the pickers are null in the database.

Comment: You can insert a default value to the database when you insert the model at the first time, if the user validates the page without refilling the pickers

Comment: This is OK for a new item in the table, but if the user makes a modification, this default value will probably not be the one that was saved, because I cannot display this value in the picker (while I can display it in a label).

Answer (score 0):

I probably made a mistake in the BindingContext, but I found a way to work around the problem. I removed the Binding in the xaml code:

```
<Picker x:Name="pickerCat" SelectedIndexChanged="pickerCat_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

And I added a few lines in the code behind:

```
if (_article.NomCat == null)
        {
            pickerCat.Title = "choisissez une catégorie";
            pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Gray;
        }
else
        {
            pickerCat.Title = _article.NomCat;
            pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
string[] pickerListCat;
List<string> pkListCat = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in DB_CategorieList_Sorted)
       {
           string element = item.NomCat;
           pkListCat.Add(element);
       }
pickerListCat = pkListCat.ToArray();
pickerCat.ItemsSource = pickerListCat;

private void pickerCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = (string)pickerCat.SelectedItem;
        if (_article != null)
            _article.NomCat = selectedItem;
    }
```

Now it works very well: the value of the field is displayed in the picker after reading the element in the table.

Comment: Thanks for you sharing, please do not mark this answer, it will help others who have similar issue.